# Center a FormLayout in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have ASP.NET WebForms project. I need to center ASPxFormLayout (it's control from DevExpress). I already center title, but I've tried everhyting and can't center FormLayout. Is this possible?

## aspx

```
<section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1><%: Title %></h1>
            </hgroup>

            <dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="ASPxFormLayout1" runat="server">
</dx:ASPxFormLayout>
            </div>
    </section>
```

## .css

```
.featured {
    /*background-color: #fff;*/
}

    .featured .content-wrapper {
        background-color: red;
        /*
        background-color: #7ac0da;
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #7ac0da), color-stop(1, #a4d4e6));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        color: #3e5667;
            padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
            */
    }

        .featured hgroup.title h1, .featured hgroup.title h2 {
            color: black;
        }

        .featured p {
            font-size: 1.1em;
        }

/* page titles */
hgroup.title {
    /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
    text-align: center;
}

hgroup.title h1, hgroup.title h2 {
    display: inline;
}

hgroup.title h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

/* features */
section.feature {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML output?

Comment: No need. There is title on center and form on left without paddings etc. I just want to stick form to center.

Comment: I know this is a bad resolution but have you tried just putting that element in <center></center> tags?